# use-parent-handlers="false" does not work

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I hope I am doing wrong and can say what it is.
I am Using JBoss EAP 7.0.4.

I have a problem with logging, that although i defined `use-parent-handers="false"` every log is also printed in the root logger (=console).

This ist form my standalone.xml:

```
<profile>  
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">  
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">  
                <level name="TRACE"/>  
                <formatter>  
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>  
                </formatter>  
            </console-handler>  
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">  
                <formatter>  
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>  
                </formatter>  
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>  
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>  
                <append value="true"/>  
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>  
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="TEST" autoflush="true">  
                <formatter>  
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>  
                </formatter>  
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="test.log"/>  
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>  
                <append value="true"/>  
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>  
            <logger category="org.jboss.modules" use-parent-handlers="false">  
                <level name="TRACE"/>  
                <handlers>  
                    <handler name="TEST"/>  
                </handlers>  
            </logger>  
            <root-logger>  
                <level name="INFO"/>  
                <handlers>  
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>  
                    <handler name="FILE"/>  
                </handlers>  
            </root-logger>  
            <formatter name="PATTERN">  
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>  
            </formatter>  
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">  
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>  
            </formatter>  
        </subsystem>
```

After adding this logger:

```
<logger category="org.jboss.modules" use-parent-handlers="false">  
                <level name="TRACE"/>  
                <handlers>  
                    <handler name="TEST"/>  
                </handlers>  
            </logger>
```

every trace is also printed to console.

After removing this logger again, console prints as expected.

As far as I understand this would be normal behaviour if I did not defined use-parent-handlers="false" but I did and I do not understand why it is not working.

If you need further information, feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to execute the following CLI commands and see trace logging not appear on the console.

```
/subsystem=logging/periodic-rotating-file-handler=TEST:add(named-formatter=PATTERN, suffix=".yyyy-MM-dd", append=true, autoflush=true, file={relative-to=jboss.server.log.dir, path=test.log})  
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.jboss.modules:add(use-parent-handlers=false, handlers=[TEST], level=TRACE)  
:reload
```

The `:reload` isn't required, but will reload the server so it will show the logging you'd want to see.